# Elementary OS: Freya and Opera 34

Tags: applications

I am using Opera as my default browser in daily basis but I want to change the.. hmm.. header? The gray thing over the top, above the Opera logo. I want to make it like it is on Ubuntu and Windows. The same problem I have with Linux Mint too, and in the Opera's settings there's not an option to change that. Any ideas how to remove the the gray header above the Opera logo?

Comment: "above the logo"? The header is needed to manage tabs, correct?

Comment: Is there any ways to change gray color? Opera looks kinda ugly now on Elementary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to make opera as in Ubuntu. Because, no menu options available in elementary like `File  Edit    View    Bookmarks   Widgets Tools   Help`. So the only way to access the menu options is via logo at present.

Comment: Seems that you are right! I talk to the Opera developers and they confirm that Opera can't change the design in Elementary OS. Thank you for your answer.